# How to verify client-certificate in AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm new to Lambda... Assuming I have an API Gateway that invokes my Lambda function (node.js) upon some HTTPS POST request from the web, how do I perform SSL peer authentication of the original HTTP client?

For example, let's say some server on the internet performs an HTTP POST to my API Gateway, which in turn invokes my Lambda. I want my Lambda to allow requests only from a client whose SSL certificate is associated to a specific domain..

thanks!

Comment: Is this what you meant? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html

Comment: Not exactly: if I understand correctly, the feature you refer to allows me to make sure it's the API Gateway (and not anyone else) that invokes my lambda. But it tells me nothing about the identify of the client that called my API to begin with. To clarify: let's say I use hurl.it website to send an HTTPS request to my API gateway.. how can I verify that my API/lambda is only accessible by hurl.it and nobody else?

Comment: Just posting this as a comment since it is not a direct answer but may help steer you in the right direction. http://benfoster.io/blog/aws-api-gateway-ip-restrictions

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/faqs/

Comment: I was looking for a similar solution as you, but so far I must conclude that API Gateway does not offer any way of relaying client side certificate information to Lambda authorizers. Did you eventually find a solution?

Comment: No, back then I eventually sticked to EC2 with network ELB (which allows me to setup my own ssl handler in Node.js on the EC2 machine). I skipped APIW altogether. It's possible that there's also another APIGW-based solution available since then, but didn't have time to check :)

Answer (score 1):

Lambda does not deal with SSL certificates. API Gateway does.

Also, API Gateway does not provide you with HTTP endpoints, only HTTPS.

From the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/faqs/):

> **Q: Can I create HTTPS endpoints?**
>
> Yes, all of the APIs created with Amazon API Gateway expose HTTPS endpoints only. Amazon API Gateway does not support unencrypted (HTTP) endpoints. By default, Amazon API Gateway assigns an internal domain to the API that automatically uses the Amazon API Gateway certificate. When configuring your APIs to run under a custom domain name, you can provide your own certificate for the domain.

To set up your specific domain, see the following link:

[Set up Custom Domain Name for API Host Name](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html)

Comment: This means my Lambda function has no knowledge of the certificate coming from the "outside world" - only of the certificate of my API Gateway?

Comment: Lambda has no knowledge of any certificate at all. Lambda simply receives the input passed by API Gateway which you can see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-set-up-simple-proxy.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format).

Comment: APIGW setting up its own client-cert is nice, but is it capable of verifying the cert of its own incoming clients? That's what I'm basically looking for... i.e. how can I tell APIGW which client CAs/certs it can trust.. I didn't find this option, guess I'll stick to basic ec2 web servers in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The Lambda authorizer is passed in Cert data from the request.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-input.html

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: My apologies. The following example provided in this link shows an input to a REQUEST authorizer for an API method (GET /request) with a proxy integration. Here, you will notice the "clientCert" property which carries certain values from the cert used in the request.